# Read from a file. C++

Tags: c++

SO when my program starts, it attempts to read a list of products from a file. but if the file does not exist it displays an error and continue on. the problem im having is when it displays the error, it doesnt continue on to the do while loop

```
ifstream input;
    input.open("data.txt");


    if (input.fail())
    {
        cout << "\n Data file not found \n";
    }
    ListItemType data; 

    input >> data.productname;
    while(( !input.eof()))
    {
        input >> data.category;
        input >> data.productprice;
        addproduct(head, data); 
        input >> data.productname;
    }

    input.close();
```

Comment: what is in your do-while loop, show the code?

Comment: Wait... you want it to attempt to read, even if the file does not exist?

Comment: I guess `input.eof()` is never true when the stream can't be opened. So the `while` loop repeats forever.

Comment: the do while is a menu. ive added it to the code above

Comment: when the program starts, i try to load the the items from the file, if theres no saved file, the program shld continue to display the menu

Comment: @user1896464 you missed the while clause in do-while loop?

Comment: @user1896464 the while clause seems not being put at correct position since your switch is not ended in this case, I guess it is a typo. The only guess I can think of is that when you call getNumberProduct(head) after do, it silently bail out. you may need to put a break point at that function and step in to see what happened.

Answer (score 1):

It's not identical functionality, but it's generally better to move towards something like:

```
if (std::ifstream input("data.txt"))
{
    ListItemType data; 
    while (input >> data.productname >> data.category >> data.productprice >> data.productname)
        addproduct(head, data);
    if (!input.eof())
        std::cerr << "Error parsing input file.\n";
}    
else
    cout << "\n Data file not found \n";
```

If you structure your if/else clauses as above, whatever happens it will continue to the following code as you'd like.

Note that the code above checks for a problem after each input operation.  Your code tries to read data.productprice even if reading data.category failed.  It's kind of weird you're reading productname twice, and I'm assuming you can call addproduct after the I/O - if not you'll need a while loop like:

```
    while (input >> data.productname >> data.category >> data.productprice)
    {
        addproduct(head, data);
        if (!(input >> data.productname))
            break;
    }
```